# Value update if object exist and create if not under array mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this:

```
[
   {
      "createdate": "2020-06-03T18:30:00.000Z",
      "hold": [
         {
            "time": "12:30",
            "user": [
               "5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time": "13:00",
            "user": [
               "5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time": "13:30",
            "user": [
               "5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "_id": "5ed745c38b4d8646601bad1d",
      "__v": 0
   },
   {
      "createdate": "2020-06-04T18:30:00.000Z",
      "hold": [
         {
            "time": "12:30",
            "user": [
               "5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time": "13:00",
            "user": [
               "5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time": "13:30",
            "user": [
               "5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "_id": "5ed745c3404a701fb888e732",
      "__v": 0
   }
]
```

Now I want to update some data on these two enteries, let's say I have to update **"13:00"** on both the enteries to push *5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe*, and create/push new object **"14:30"** with user id i.e *5ed8ae4891501a1c10246dfe*.

Also check if id already exist on user array then don't perform anything.

> userdata = [{"startdate": "2020, 6, 4", "enddate": "2020, 6, 4", "time": ["12:30", "13:00","13:30"]}]
>   userdata is the data which we have to update on collection.
>   What I tried is like:

```
let userdata  = [{ "startdate": "2020, 6, 4", "enddate": "2020, 6, 5", "time": ["12:30", "13:00", "13:30"] }]
const test = async () => {
    try {
    // I am Using mongoose, so CollectionName is dummy name to share
        let data = [];
        let getCalenderData = await CollectionName.find(
            { createdate: { $gte: new Date(userdata[0].startdate), $lte: new Date(userdata[0].enddate) } }
        ).exec();
        console.log(getCalenderData)
        if (getCalenderData.length > 0) {
            data = getCalenderData;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3))
    // So here what I tried to achieve is first on one query pull all data,
    // then using filter function to segregate the data,
   // then after this set push or pull the data at single query.
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

test();
```

But I have confusion that this approach would be little lengthier than Database query. We have tan option to solve this through javascript but in terms of Database there must me some smart query which perform all these task in a few lines rather than using the Javascript.

Any expert of MongoDB Database, please suggest me how to perform this through DB Query rather than javascript. Any help from the experts will be really really appreciated. *Thanks in Advance*